# Parsing an "integer" time with DateTimeFormatter using optional sections

Tags: java, datetime, date-formatting, java-time

I some DB, I have some custom format for [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) and I am trying to build a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for it.

There are following rules:

- 0 => 00:00
- 10 => 00:10
- 111 => 1:11
- 101 => 1:01
- 1111 => 11:11

It is possible to have optional sections with [] in such a formatter, but I am not sure if it is possible to apply these rules to such a formatter.

When using `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("Hmm")`, 900 and 1111 can be parsed, but 11 (obviously) not.

But using `[H]mm`, neither 900 nor 1111 can be parsed.

However `[HH]mm`, can parse 1111, but not 900

I tried something like

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[HH][m]m");
    // or

    formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[H]mm");

    System.out.println(LocalTime.parse("1111",formatter));
    System.out.println(LocalTime.parse("900",formatter));
    System.out.println(LocalTime.parse("1",formatter));
    System.out.println(LocalTime.parse("11",formatter));
    System.out.println(LocalTime.parse("201",formatter));
    System.out.println(LocalTime.parse("1000",formatter));
    System.out.println(LocalTime.parse("0",formatter));

// assertions

    assertThat(LocalTime.parse("1111",formatter), CoreMatchers.equalTo(LocalTime.of(11,11)));
    assertThat(LocalTime.parse("900",formatter), CoreMatchers.equalTo(LocalTime.of(9,00)));
    assertThat(LocalTime.parse("1",formatter), CoreMatchers.equalTo(LocalTime.of(0,1)));
    assertThat(LocalTime.parse("201",formatter), CoreMatchers.equalTo(LocalTime.of(2,1)));
    assertThat(LocalTime.parse("1000",formatter), CoreMatchers.equalTo(LocalTime.of(10,0)));
    assertThat(LocalTime.parse("0",formatter), CoreMatchers.equalTo(LocalTime.of(0,0)));
```

but this does not work, throwing exceptions like

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '1111' could not be parsed at index 4

Comment: A pattern like "Hmm|m" would be nice if supported by `java.time` where "|" indicates an or-logic. See also this [small example](https://gist.github.com/MenoData/ed74417a7383ca6c13e5) using another library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no pattern in `DateTimeFormatter` that will parse what you want. Furthermore, `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` cannot help you. The main problem is that the parser is greedy, so anything that is setup will parse the first one/two digits as the hour, leaving what remains for the minute. This doesn't match your spec.

Option 1:

Use this approach:

```
DateTimeFormatter f = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendValue(HOUR_OF_DAY)
    .appendValue(MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
    .toFormatter();
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse("0000" + str, f);
```

This approach makes the pattern regular, with a fixed number of digits for minutes. It should be noted that `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("Hmm")` will also work, but I used the long form above to make it more obvious.

Option 2:

Write an implementation of `TemporalField` that handles the integer format defined above. Then use that in `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`. This is a lot harder and overkill for this need, but mentioned here for completeness.

Comment: `There is no pattern in DateTimeFormatter that will parse what you want. Furthermore, DateTimeFormatterBuilder cannot help you.` See my answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .optionalStart()
            .appendValue(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2)
            .appendValue(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
            .optionalEnd()
            .optionalStart()
            .appendValue(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1)
            .appendValue(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
            .optionalEnd()
            .optionalStart()
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
            .appendValue(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR)
            .optionalEnd()
            .toFormatter();
```

Comment: well it seems to work ;) still, the solution with padding the time to make it regular seems to be easier to understand from a perspective of maintainability